# How to set up prefix for steps method for whispering in Intellij

Tags: cucumber

If cucumber step definition starts with value, then IntelliJ doesn´t whisper code and we need to copy/paste it. Guys from team agreed to put some prefix unique for each method/process to help IntelliJ whisper. There is also condition that already existing steps which begins with value should be accepted as usual without any necessary code change.

I have tried to do something like code below to accept value or prefix with pipe but IntelliJ doesn´t whisper but code pass without error.

```
@Given("^DB:SQL UPDATE |.*, SQL UPDATE: (.*)$")
    public void update(String sql) throws SQLException {

        .......
```

We expect IntelliJ to whisper code using this prefix and others when writting step definintion like this:

```
Scenario Outline: Task list for team inbox filtered by org units

    Given Empty OrgUnits table, SQL UPDATE: DELETE FROM r_org_unit
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

```
@And("^.*, SQL UPDATE: (.*)$")
@Then("^DB:SQL .*, SQL UPDATE: (.*)$")
    public void update(String sql) throws SQLException {
```

From now when you start writting code like
And up... IntelliJ will whisper you as well as
And DB... also whispering method

Thanks.